# How to change a css property with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the `margin-top` css element of a div using javascript but its not working. Here is my code:

```
document.getElementById("sidescrollbtn").css({'margin-top':'70px'});
```

Any ideas?

***Fiddle:*** http://jsfiddle.net/vinicius5581/2y63xnxa/5/

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: I am. I could be using $("sidescrollbtn") instead of document.getElementById("sidescrollbtn") I guess, but that wouldn't make a difference, right?

Comment: @ViniciusSantana it makes difference. Javascript has DOM object whereas jQuery has jQuery object. if you want to use jquery methods, then you must use jquery object.

Answer (score 3):

In vanilla JS, just set `.style.{camelCasedProperty} = 'value';`

```
document.getElementById("sidescrollbtn").style.marginTop = '70px';
```

You can also do it with jQuery using the object notation you tried:

```
$('#sidescrollbtn').css({ 'margin-top': '70px' });
```

Comment: @wintermute just getting the answer in there first, I always explain :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it a several ways:

```
// Reference property name
document.getElementById("sidescrollbtn").style.marginTop = '70px';
```

OR

```
// Use setAttribute method
document.getElementById("sidescrollbtn").setAttribute("style", "margin-top: 70px");
```

OR

```
// Use jquery .css()
$('#sidescrollbtn').css({ 'margin-top': '70px' });
```

**Additional Information**

- [Element.setAttribute() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute)
- [css() on jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: @NishanthiGrashia, I do not consider making my `OR`'s bold a legitimate edit. If I wanted them bold, I would have made them bold.

Answer (score 1):

Use **HTML DOM**

```
document.getElementById(id).style.property=new style
```

***Example:***

```
<script>
document.getElementById("p2").style.color = "blue";
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can give css using

```
document.getElementById("p2").style.color = "blue";
```

Answer (score 0):

In the JSFiddle you created, this will work if you replace the line of code having issue with the below line of code.

```
document.getElementById("sidescrollbtn").style.marginTop = '70px';
```

You can also apply style by using jQuery as below

```
$('#sidescrollbtn').css({ 'margin-top': '70px' });
```